# Why I get INTERNAL SERVER ERROR when i login into tryton sao web client

Tags: tryton

I install successfully the sao web interface.
The login form apper in the webpage, but when i try to confirm the login i get INTERNAL SERVER ERROR MESSAGE.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxLGo.png)

also in the shell I get the following errors:

```
26573 140363546924800 [2020-02-08 09:16:06,444] INFO werkzeug  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit) 26573 140363423508224 [2020-02-08 09:16:10,855] INFO werkzeug 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2020 09:16:10] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 - 26573 140363423508224 [2020-02-08 09:16:10,936] INFO werkzeug 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2020 09:16:10] "GET /custom.js HTTP/1.0" 405 - 26573 140363410827008 [2020-02-08 09:16:10,937] INFO werkzeug 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2020 09:16:10] "GET /custom.css HTTP/1.0" 405 - 26573 140363410827008 [2020-02-08 09:16:11,094] INFO werkzeug 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2020 09:16:11] "GET /custom.js HTTP/1.0" 405 - 26573 140363410827008 [2020-02-08 09:16:11,130] INFO werkzeug 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2020 09:16:11] "GET /custom.css HTTP/1.0" 405 - 26573 140363410827008 [2020-02-08 09:16:11,176] INFO werkzeug 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2020 09:16:11] "GET /locale/en_GB.json HTTP/1.0" 405 - 26573 140363410827008 [2020-02-08 09:16:11,181] INFO werkzeug 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2020 09:16:11] "GET /images/tryton-icon.png HTTP/1.0" 200 - 26573 140363410827008 [2020-02-08 09:16:11,216] INFO werkzeug
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2020 09:16:11] "GET /locale/en.json HTTP/1.0" 405 - 26573 140363410827008 [2020-02-08 09:16:11,312] INFO werkzeug
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2020 09:16:11] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 500 - 26573 140363410827008 [2020-02-08 09:16:11,314] ERROR werkzeug Error on request: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 323, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 312, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trytond/wsgi.py", line 181, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trytond/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trytond/wsgi.py", line 159, in wsgi_app
    abort(HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 822, in abort
    return _aborter(status, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 807, in __call__
    raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs) werkzeug.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. 26573 140363410827008 [2020-02-08 09:16:21,520] INFO werkzeug 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2020 09:16:21] "POST /t_test_comune/ HTTP/1.0" 500 - 26573 140363410827008 [2020-02-08 09:16:21,522] ERROR werkzeug Error on request: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 323, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 312, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trytond/wsgi.py", line 181, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trytond/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trytond/wsgi.py", line 159, in wsgi_app
    abort(HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 822, in abort
    return _aborter(status, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/tryton/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 807, in __call__
    raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs) werkzeug.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
```

I cannot understated why I get the permission access problem
any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a CORS issue. So the Origin host and the Host headers are not the same. It is probably because your reverse proxy is not correctly setup. You must ensure that the header X-Forwarded-Host is set with the original host and the [num_proxies](https://docs.tryton.org/projects/server/en/latest/topics/configuration.html#num-proxies) of trytond configuration.